# What am I doing wrong in hosting my Web API app on the network?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, application-pool

I followed the steps in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/726369/Run-ASP-NET-Website-on-Network-through-IIS-8-0?msg=4761866#xx4761866xx), yet when I enter my IP address (machine name) and the port number that I set up following those instructions (namely 8090) in my browser, I just see a directory listing of my site:

[image]

Note: Using the direct IP Address (in place of the machine name) gives the exact same results.

For a Web API site/app, do I need something appended to the plain IP Address/MachineName + Port number URL?

According to IIS Manager, I was successful in setting up the app to run:

[image]

Web API apps do not have a Default.aspx "startng point" page or some such; is there something else analogous that I should use? I tried:

```
http://shannon2:8090/Web.config
```

...but that gave me:

***HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.***

What step[s] am I missing?

Note: The article referenced has an IIS 8 download, but according to Control Panel, I already had IIS 8 installed, so I didn't re-install it. Yet, the About box for IIS Manager says it is version 7.5.7600.16385 (?!?)

Is there a way to force the usage of version 8 instead of this one? Does it matter in this scenario?

### UPDATE

Based on what I read here [http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2014/02/18/the-world-s-simplest-angularjs-example-in-visual-studio.aspx], specifically "By convention, the main file of an application is Index.html", I also tried this:

```
http://shannon2:8090/Index.html
```

...but got:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

But I don't really have an Index.html file in my project, so that's was a shot in the dark/leap of gullibility, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the directory listing because the page you are referring to tells you to enable directory browsing.

I am not sure what the gentleman was trying to convey in that link. I think he is trying to convey how to access your "files" within the network. However, disable directory browsing and you should be ok.

And web API should run in managed pipeline within the application pool settings.

Comment: When I disable directory browsing, it does take effect, because now, when I try to navigate to http://shannon2:8090, I get:
"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."
So how do I set Web API to "run in managed pipeline"?
BTW: Are you really Genghis Khan's mother?

Comment: The two options are "Classic" and "Integrated"; are you agreeing or disagreeing with the cat who wrote that article (who recommends "Classic")? With either setting the results are the same (Error 403.14).